# putting absolute position div overtop last image

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have the following code which targets the last image in my Wordpress post and puts `#first-img` on it, it leaves the other images alone.

```
  <div id="s-img" class="row">      
    <?php
        preg_match_all('/(<img [^>]*>)/', get_the_content(), $images);
        for( $i=0; isset($images[1]) && $i < count($images[1]); $i++ ) {
        if ($i == end(array_keys($images[1]))) {
        echo sprintf('<div id="last-img">%s</div>', $images[1][$i]);
        continue;
        }
            echo $images[1][$i];
        }
    ?> 
</div>
```

css

```
#last-image { 
   position: absolute
   height: 50px; width: 50px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

Problem is I want it to put `#first-img` ON-TOP of the image and leave the image itself alone. Right now it replaces the image.

Rendered html - on images and last image

```
<div id="s-img" class="row">        
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-396" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/img3-1008x720.jpg" alt="img3" height="720" width="1008"> </img>
</div>

<div id="last-img">
<img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-397" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/img4-1080x720.jpg" alt="img4" height="720" width="1080"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML from the browser because PHP code will not be useful

Comment: Please Copy and paste it the screen shot will not help debugging the issue, Thanks

Comment: Add to `.row` div - `position:relative`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is I want it to put #first-img ON-TOP of the image and leave the image itself alone

What exactly are you trying to achieve here? I don’t see you outputting any extra text content (like f.e. an image description), so I assume you just want to overlay an empty element over the image, to apply some kind of CSS effect (background-color)?

If so, you should be able to use a pseudo-element for that – not on the image itself (because elements with the empty content model can’t have those), but on the div container you put around the image:

```
#last-image { 
   position: relative;
   /* display:line-block; */ /* you might need to add that, */
                      /* if the image is not covering full width */
}
#last-image:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; /* automatically stretch */
                                   /* to full parent width/height */
   background-color: red;
   z-index: 1; /* might not be necessary, depends on rest of CSS */
}
```

Comment: The way it is written the #last-image is connected to the image. I have more than one image in the post. I don't want to change the css of the images, I just want to put a div over-top the last one. All css applied to #last-img just applied to the div on-top of the last image. Not to the image itself. Which is the issue it is having now

Comment: Have you even tried what I suggested? If so, what part of your requirements does it not fulfill?

Comment: I have and there is no change, the image remains but nothing shows on top (I've tried with and without the commented sections)

Comment: Well then show us a working example please, where we can look at the actual situation.

Comment: unfortunately its all brought in through wordpress, javascript, etc. I don't know how to recreate that

Answer (score -1):

z-index will place the image 'above' all others, as well as 'above' every other page element with a lower z-index.

```
#first-img { 
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: problem is that as is, this also posts the last pic overtop of everything else since they are connected

Comment: did I get something wrong ?  I understood the #first-img should be placed, absolutely positioned, above the others.  or did you want it placed sequentially before other images, as with `appendChild()`.  Looks like my misunderstanding cost me a neg.  wish people were as fast to offer something constructive instead of just spitting venom.

Comment: I don't know why either, My issue is that the #first-img is linked to the image as well, so If I change the z index if affects the image and whatever else. I need the div to be seperate. target the last image but don't change it. I want css to apply to the div on-top of it